# KinectRegion Hand Cursor not showing up

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm running a fresh install of Windows 10 with Kinect SDK v2 and VS 2015. Kinect Configuration Verifier is all green lights.

Without modifying any code, both the Kinect sample **Controls Basics-WPF** from the SDK Browser and the [Kinect 2 for Windows Demo App](http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/lab10/index.html) tutorial #10 don't show the hand cursor. These samples use Microsoft.Kinect.Wpf.Controls and the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls respectively to build the KinectRegion.

Is anyone else having this problem? How can I troubleshoot this?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I didnt find any solution, but seems like this issue happens only on Windows 10. I used the same app on Windows 8 and it worked fine.

For me the solution was to port the app to WPF

Comment: I wish I documented this better, but I did fix the problem. I just don't know what I did to fix it. I suspect it was some framework or VS update that did the trick. Hope no one else runs into this issue.

Comment: Can anyone tell what they did to fix it ?